# Azure POS and weather data analysis strategy

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have a question about an approach of a solution in Azure. The question is how to decide what technologies to use and how to find the best combination of them.

Let's suppose i have two data sets, which are growing daily:

1. I have a CSV file which comes daily to my ADL store and it contains weather data for all possible Lattitudes and Longtitudes combinations and zip codes for them, together with 50 different weather variables.
2. I have another dataset with POS (point of sales), which also comes as a daily CSV file to my ADL storage. It contains sales data for all retail locations.

The desired output is to have the files "shredded" in a way that the data is prepared for AzureML forecasting of sales based on weather, and the forecasting is done per retail location and delivered via PowerBI dashboard to each one of them. A requirement is not to allow different location see the forecasts for any other locations.

My questions are:

1. How do I choose the right set of technologies?
2. how do I append the incoming daily data?
3. How do I create a separate ML forecasting results for each location?

Any general guidance on the architecture topic is appreciated, and any more specific ideas on comparison of different suitable solutions is also appreciated.

Comment: This is a really broad, opinion-soliciting discussion topic. Also a tool-recommendation question (as you're seeking comparison of different solutions / technologies). Unfortunately, off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

This is way to broad of a question.

I will only answer your ADL specific question #2 and give you a hint on #3 that is not related to Azure ML (since I don't know what that format is):

1. If you just use files, add date/time information to your file path name (either in folder or filename). Then use U-SQL File sets to query the ranges you are interested in. If you use U-SQL Tables, use `PARTITIONED BY`. For more details look in the [U-SQL Reference documentation](http://aka.ms/usql_reference).
2. If you need to create more than one file as output, you have two options:

   a. you know all file names, write an OUTPUT statement for each file selecting only the relevant data for it.

   b. you have to dynamically generate a script and then execute it. Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40814748/u-sql-script-to-search-for-a-string-then-groupby-that-string-and-get-the-count-o/40853423#40853423).